# Put one value in PORTA, and another value appears (PIC24 from Microchip)

Tags: pic, microchip, debugging, port

I am doing a small code for PIC24FJ1024GB610 from Microchip, where I want to test `PORTA`

### The code Below

```
#include <xc.h>


#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC
#pragma config ICS = PGD2

unsigned int Pattern;

void Ports (void)
{
    TRISA = 0x0000;//all outputs
    ANSAbits.ANSA6 = 0;
    ANSAbits.ANSA7 = 0;
    ANSAbits.ANSA9 = 0;
    ANSAbits.ANSA10 = 0;//all digital ports

    LATA = Pattern;


}


int main (void)
{
    Pattern = 0xBBAA;

    Ports ();


    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

What I expected to happen was:

- `Pattern` is declared as an `unsigned int`
- at `main ()` `Pattern = 0xBBAA`
- Program calls `Ports ()`
- `PORTA` configured as Output `TRISA = 0x0000`
- `PORTA` is configured as Digital `ANSA = 0x0000`
- `LATA = Pattern`, if I debug the program, I would expect `LATA = 0xBBAA` in the SFR window.

When I debug the program, and open the SFR window, I get `LATA = 0x82AA`, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

---

Helpful info:

- I am using Development Board "16/32 Explorer Development Board", from Microchip
- IDE: "MPLAB X IDE"
- [PIC24FJ1024GB610 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30010074e.pdf)

---

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't supply a link to the datasheet, so I didn't look it up.  My guess is that not all 16 bits of port A are implemented.

Port A pins also are sometimes used for the oscillator pins, the MCLR input, etc.  Those aren't available as port A digital pins when those other roles are used.

You really need to **read the datasheet**.

Comment: [PIC24FJ1024GA610/GB610 FAMILY](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30010074e.pdf) - Indeed, not all pins of PortA exist physically. Out of all the ports on a PIC, PortA is typically the most "limited." What is connected to PortD, Adam? That seems to have all 16 pins.

Comment: You guys were right, some pins are removed from the microcontroller.

@Olin Lathrop I shall edit, and add a link to the datasheet.

Thanks for the help